# NoMethodError After Upgrade to ActiveRecord 7.1, But Removing ActiveRecord::Base.logger Fixes

Tags: aws-lambda, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7

For context, this is a Ruby 3.2 app on AWS Lambda with ActiveRecord 7.1.2.

- I can run this locally on my M3 MacBook irb with no problem.
- I can downgrade to ActiveRecord 7.0.8 and AWS Lambda (Ruby 3.2) has no problem.

Here is the error log:
#<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass> "NoMethodError: undefined method` []' for nil:NilClass"
"["/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/logger-1.6.0/lib/logger.rb:384:in `level'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/logger_thread_safe_level.rb:39:in` level'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/logger_thread_safe_level.rb:13:in `debug?'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/log_subscriber.rb:90:in` block in class:LogSubscriber'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/log_subscriber.rb:146:in `silenced?'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:207:in` block (2 levels) in groups_for'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:207:in `reject'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:207:in` block in groups_for'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:206:in `each'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:206:in` groups_for'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:238:in `initialize'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:277:in` new'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:277:in `build_handle'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:79:in` build_handle'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:55:in `instrument'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:1143:in` log'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/trilogy/database_statements.rb:45:in `raw_execute'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:521:in` internal_execute'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:918:in `configure_connection'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:693:in` block (2 levels) in reconnect!'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:376:in `reset_transaction'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:691:in` block in reconnect!'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/null_lock.rb:9:in `synchronize'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:684:in` reconnect!'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:788:in `verify!'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:795:in` connect!'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:1001:in `block in with_raw_connection'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/null_lock.rb:9:in` synchronize'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:1000:in `with_raw_connection'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/trilogy_adapter.rb:209:in` get_full_version'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:87:in `get_database_version'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:374:in` database_version'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:70:in `database_version'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:200:in` database_version'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:871:in `database_version'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:657:in` check_version'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:675:in `new_connection'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:720:in` checkout_new_connection'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:699:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:657:in` acquire_connection'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in` connection'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_handler.rb:246:in `retrieve_connection'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:287:in` retrieve_connection'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:254:in `connection'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:618:in` load_schema!'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:264:in `load_schema!'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/encryption/encryptable_record.rb:127:in` load_schema!'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:563:in `block in load_schema'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:560:in` synchronize'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:560:in `load_schema'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:425:in` columns_hash'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:1796:in `arel_column'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:417:in` aggregate_column'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:437:in `execute_simple_calculation'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:406:in` perform_calculation'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:224:in `calculate'\", \"/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:92:in` count'", "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.2/lib/active_record/querying.rb:23:in `count'\", \"/var/task/fn/router_test.rb:28:in` router_test'", "/var/task/router.rb:5:in `router'\", \"/var/runtime/lib/lambda_handler.rb:26:in` call_handler'", "/var/runtime/lib/runtime.rb:100:in `'"]"

Here is the offending code:

```
  begin
    specs[:UsersCount] = User.count
  rescue StandardError => e
    pp e
    pp e.message
    pp e.backtrace.inspect
  end
```

init.rb

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    adapter:     'trilogy',
    database:    awsssm_get_param("/#{ENV['PREFIX'].gsub("-","/")}/db/name"),
    host:        awsssm_get_param("/#{ENV['PREFIX'].gsub("-","/")}/db/host"),
    username:    awsssm_get_param("/#{ENV['PREFIX'].gsub("-","/")}/db/user"),
    password:    awsssm_get_param("/#{ENV['PREFIX'].gsub("-","/")}/db/pass"),
    port:        4000,
    ssl_mode:    'VERIFY_IDENTITY',
  )
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
rescue StandardError => e
  pp e
  pp e.message
  pp e.backtrace.inspect
end
```

If I comment out this line: "ActiveRecord::Base.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)"

Then everything works fine, except I no longer see SQL queries in my logs.

I would like to see SQL queries in my logs.

I tried downgrading ActiveRecord to 7.0.8, which works. I tried locally on my M3 MacBook, and that works.

Comment: The fix was locking logger to 1.5.3 in my Gemfile and then my logging setup looks like:

ActiveRecord::Base.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
ActiveRecord.verbose_query_logs = true